# boundedness of a sequence of positive reals

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $a_k\in\mathbb{R_{\geq0}}$. Assume that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\big(a_{k+1}-a_k\big)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^k a_i}$ exists. Can we prove or disprove by counterexample that $a_k$ is a bounded sequence?